# how to convert char* to LPCTSTR in c++(MFC)

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, type-conversion

I have to make MFC application that accesses .txt files.
The following code is part of the template file given:

```
fopen(dlg.GetPathName());
```

However when I tried to run given template file, I got errors indicating that char* can not be converted to LPCTSTR.
I did some research online, and the program runs fine after correcting like this:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
const char* cstr;

cstr = T2A((LPCTSTR)dlg.GetPathName());
~
fp = fopen(cstr, "r");
```

I'm mentioning this because my compiler(VS 2017 community) may use unicode as default. And I think this is key to solving the aforementioned problem:

I have a problem printing result on the window edit control.

```
m_Result.SetWindowTextW((LPCTSTR)Result);
```

Result contains the message to be displayed in edit control and its type is char*. Whenever I run the program the result it is displayed either in blank box □ or Chinese. I tried converting Result using A2T and CA2T and but none of these worked.

Comment: The solution to your problem is to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). Throwing random macros and C-style casts at objects is **not** part of the solution.

Comment: `(LPCTSTR)dlg.GetPathName()` and this `((LPCTSTR)Result)` -- These are all wrong.  You are not converting from one character type to another by casting.  All you're doing here is stopping the compiler from telling you about your errors.  Remove the casts and either 1) **Properly convert** from one type to another by calling the appropriate functions or 2) Use the **correct** string types from the start.  Regardless, you either do 1) or 2)  **without any C- style casts**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error can be fixed by using Microsoft's `_wfopen()` function (or the `TCHAR` equivalent, `_tfopen()`, to match the `TCHAR` nature of `GetPathName()` instead of `fopen()`.  That way, you don't need to convert the input string to `char*` at all:

```
fp = _wfopen(dlg.GetPathName(), L"r");
```

```
fp = _tfopen(dlg.GetPathName(), _T("r"));
```

In the second error, if `Result` is `char*` (or something that is implicitly convertible to `char*`) and `LPCTSTR` maps to `const wchar_t*` (because `UNICODE` is defined) then you can use `CA2CT` just fine:

```
m_Result.SetWindowTextW(CA2CT(Result));
```

However, since `SetWindowTextW()` expects only `wchar_t*` and never `TCHAR*`, use `CA2CW` instead:

```
m_Result.SetWindowTextW(CA2CW(Result));
```

Alternatively, if possible, you should change `Result` to use `wchar_t` instead of `char` in the first place, then you don't need a conversion anymore:

```
m_Result.SetWindowTextW(Result);
```